# Two-way fixed effects model: Is non-random treatment a problem here?

Tags: mixed-model, least-squares, econometrics, causality

Consider the following panel regression model, were we try to estimate whether Photovoltaic Panels (PV) installations on apartment blocks have a driving effect on adoption speed of surrounding dwellings:

\begin{align}
  Y_{it} &= \gamma_i  + \beta X_{it-1} + \theta_t +  \epsilon_{it} \\\\
    \end{align}

$\gamma_i$ denotes an area fixed effect.
$Y_{it}$ corresponds to the increase of PV panels on detached dwellings in area $i$ in year $t$. 
$X_{it-1}$ denotes the increase in PV panels on apartment blocks in the surrounding radius, in the year before. 
$\theta_t$ is a year fixed effect.

We assume the treatment $X$ here is not random, as the selection process for renovating apartment blocks is not random. Apartment blocks with certain building characteristics (e.g., age) are targeted first.

We also assume that surrounding detached houses share similarities in these predictive indicators for renovation. We assume that e.g., they roughly share the same built year.

We face an endogeneity issue here, as the estimates of $X$ could be biased, and the driving effect $X$ on $Y$ could be explained because of the fact the surrounding dwellings are also old.

My question is: since we added an area fixed effect, we control for unobservables, such as building age, which we believe have an effect on $Y$. However, can we still consistently and reliably estimate $\beta$? In other words, does the inclusion of the fixed effect solve our described non-random treatment?

Answer (score 0):

As with any causal effect estimation, if your intervention assignment is random given the controls, the estimate would be unbiased.
Whether or not this applies in your case would require a lot of domain knowledge to answer.

A good way forward would be to explicitly formulate the structural causal model, including the confounding you suspect affects your data. This will force you to make your assumptions explicit and give you a way of checking whether your current model would give you an unbiased estimate under these assumptions.